# Order By on the Basis of Integer present in string

Tags: c#

I've a problem in my C# application... I've some school classes in database for example 8-B, 9-A, 10-C, 11-C and so on .... when I use order by clause to sort them, the string comparison gives results as

```
10-C
11-C
8-B
9-A
```

but I want integer sorting on the basis of first integer present in string...
i.e.

```
8-B
9-A
10-C
11-C
```

hope you'll understand...
I've tried this but it throws exception

```
var query = cx.Classes.Select(x=>x.Name)
                .OrderBy( x=>  new string(x.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
```

Please help me... want ordering on the basis of classes ....

Comment: What kind of exception it throws?

Comment: have you tried `int.Parse(new string(...`?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is well-formed enough, this would do:

```
        var maxLen = cx.Classes.Max(x => x.Name.Length);
        var query =  cx.Classes.Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(x => x.PadLeft(maxLen));
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe `Split` will do?

```
.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('-')[0]))
.ThenBy(x => x.Split('-')[1])
```

Comment: You probably want to add in a custom Select Transform function so you only have to split once. Anonymous struct perhaps.

Comment: var query = cx.Classes.Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('-')[0]))
                            .ThenBy(x => x.Split('-')[1]);

            foreach (string x in query)
            {
                list.Add(x);
            }
Exception in loop ... System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Unrecognized expression node: ArrayIndex
  Source=System.Data.Linq

Comment: Worked for me ...

var maxLen = cx.Classes.Max(x => x.Name.Length);
        var query =  cx.Classes.Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(x => x.PadLeft(maxLen));

Answer (score 0):

You can add 0 as left padding for a specified length as your data for example 6

```
.OrderBy(x => x.PadLeft(6, '0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally the same approach as [Andrius's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764170/933416), written out more explicitly:

```
var names = new[] { "10-C", "8-B", "9-A", "11-C" };

var sortedNames =
    (from name in names
     let parts = name.Split('-')
     select new {
         fullName = name,
         number = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]),
         letter = parts[1]
     })
    .OrderBy(x => x.number)
    .ThenBy(x => x.letter)
    .Select(x => x.fullName);
```

It's my naive assumption that this would be more efficient because the `Split` is only processed once in the initial select rather than in both OrderBy and ThenBy, but for all I know the extra "layers" of LINQ may outweigh any gains from that.